# Updating some but not all elements inside renderUI output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build an interactive UI by rendering it inside an output with renderUI. The thing is: I have inputs created inside this rendering function whose behavior should change according to the answers provided. But when I do it, the reactivity updates the entire output and erases the answers provided, resetting the inputs to original state. Is there a way to determine which inputs I want to update? Or is there a better way of building this structure?

EDIT: Just to clarify: I want to change the label of the textInput without updating the radioButtons. The second radioButton answer should affect the behaviour of the textInput only.

```
ui <- miniPage(
  miniTabstripPanel(id = 'tabs',
    miniTabPanel("Data",
                 miniContentPanel(
                   selectInput(inputId = 'indicator', label = "Select indicator:",
                               choices = c('Select an indicator' = 'none',
                                           "Water" = 'iwater',
                                           'Antenatal care 4+ visits' = 'anc4',
                                           'Institutional delivery' = 'ideliv')),
                 )
    ),
    miniTabPanel("Second tab",
       miniContentPanel(
          uiOutput(outputId = "indicarea")  
       )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  iwater_vartype = reactiveVal(value= "Example label 1")
  observeEvent(input$iwater_variabletype,{
    if (input$iwater_variabletype == 'codes') {
      iwater_vartype("Example label 1")
    }
    else {
      iwater_vartype("Example label 2")
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$indicator,{
    output$indicarea = renderUI({
      buildUI(input$indicator)
    })
  })

  buildUI = function(indic) {
    switch(indic, 
           'none' = {
             h3("Please select an indicator to proceed.")
           },
           'iwater' = {
               tagList(
                  h3("Improved source of drinking water"),
                  br(), hr(), br(),
                  radioButtons(inputId = 'iwater_subsample', label = "Asked it in all?",
                              choices = c('Yes' = 'yes', 'No' = 'no')),
                  radioButtons(inputId = 'iwater_variabletype', label = "How was the info collected?",
                               choices = c('One variable' = 'codes', 'Several variables' = 'variables')),
                  textInput(inputId = 'iwater_sourcevariable', label= iwater_vartype())
               )
           },
           'anc4' = {
               tagList(
                  textInput(inputId = 'test', label= 'testing')
             )
           }
      )
  }
}

runGadget(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want different behavior, separate the `renderUI` functions: one for the buttons, one for the text input

Comment: I'm not sure I can since they are dynamic and the number of radio buttons connected to inputs may vary. I want to replicate that behavior as if it were a flowchart

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding an `observeEvent` to you server code with something like this.

```
observeEvent(input$iwater_variabletype,{
    updateTextInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = "iwater_sourcevariable",
        label = "new Label for text Input"
      )
    })
```

hope this helps!